# mcamara/laravel-localization named routes localization

Tags: php, laravel, routes, translation, multilingual

I set up [mcamara/laravel-localization 1.3](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) library in `laravel 5.6` according to the documentation and in `users` table i create `lang` column which i set every time user switch language (this allow me to send "background" cyclic emails in proper language or set proper language after user login). I set all my routes in `web.php` in group `LaravelLocalization::setLocale()` (as documentation says).

I want to use **named routes** inside my controllers e.g. for redirection to proper page after user login (user came from EN landing page, but his `lang='pl'`). When in my `LoginController@redirectTo()` I use just:

```
App::setLocale(Auth::user()->lang);
$url =  route('dashboard.index');
return $url;

// current result $url = 'http://ebnavi.localhost/en/panel/raporty'
// desired result $url = 'http://ebnavi.localhost/pl/panel/raporty'
```

It doesn't work. I don't found direct instruction in documentation about this.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few hours finally I found [this solution](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/issues/274) in internet:

```
$url = LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($locale, route($routeName));
```

And create following [helper function](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) to realize this task

```
function localRoute($routeName, $locale = null)
{
    if (!$locale && Auth::user())  $locale = Auth::user()->lang;

    return $locale ? LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($locale, route($routeName)) : route($routeName);
}
```

In our controller we can just use it in this way:

```
$url =  localRoute('dashboard.index');
```

But may be exists some better approach for this?

Comment: I have another solution. in routes/web.php, add 'as' => 'lang.', and use route(lang.login), or route(lang.admin.login). No helper is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I so solved this problem

Successful authorization, you need to send the user locale from the database

***LoginController\authenticated***

```
\LaravelLocalization::setLocale(\Auth::user()->language);
```

On the page HTML specify the active locale

```
<html lang="{{ \LaravelLocalization::setLocale(\Auth::user()->language) }}">
```